# How can we use external link in href of tag without the using base URL?

Tags: html, css, angular

How can we use external link in href of `<a>` tag without base URL in Angular ?
I found the [attr.href] for this problem. It works for like this links :`www.example.com`.

But when I added `https://www.example.com` or `http://www.example.com` then the link it doesn't work.
New link is showing as :`http://https//www.google.com`. Do you have any idea ?

in .ts file ; exampleUrl:string='https://www.google.com';

```
<div>
        <a 
        [attr.href]="'//'+exampleUrl"
         target="_blank">
            {{ exampleUrl }}
        </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `//` at the beginning means, this is a "protocol relative" URL - the `http:` or `https:` in front of it will automatically be added when this gets resolved to a full URL, depending on what protocol the page this is in uses. You simply can not use this with full, absolute URLs.